# How to run Dokka offline in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

I want to run Dokka offline to generate the documentation as the build running system doesn't need internet access so the document need to be generated offline.

Is it possible? If yes, plz suggest the same.

Thanks
Binay

As it doesn't seems working offline no information available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are `noStdlibLink`, `noJdkLink` and `noAndroidSdkLink`. If you specify all three, dokka won't connect to the Internet to download `package-list`s